# Generating MP4 from HLS in gstreamer

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, transcoding

I am trying to generate MP4s from HLS streams with discontinuity tags. Since the videos are from the same source the FPS and the WXH are the same.

I tested with the following pipeline to demux and play it and it works fine

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v souphttpsrc location=<HLS_URL> ! hlsdemux ! decodebin name=decoder \
! queue ! autovideosink decoder. ! queue ! autoaudiosink
```

To this I added the x264 enc and avenc_aac encoder to save it to a file and it keeps failing on 
`"gstadaptivedemux.c(2651): _src_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0"`

Failing Pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v  mp4mux name=mux faststart=true presentation-time=true ! filesink location=dipoza.mp4 \
souphttpsrc location=<HLS_URL> ! hlsdemux ! decodebin name=decoder ! queue name=q1 ! \
 videoconvert ! queue name=q2 ! x264enc name=encoder ! mux.  decoder. \
 ! queue name=q3 ! audioconvert ! queue name=q4 ! avenc_aac ! mux.
```

I really appreciate any help in this.

Comment: Not sure tbh. A few remarks. The recommended AAC encoder is `voaacenc` if i remember correctly. Try adding parser elements before the muxer. That is `h264parse` and `aacparse`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @FlorianZwoch. That helped me move forward. i will up vote your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I found the issue with my pipeline. Thanks a lot to @FlorianZwoch for asking me to move to voaacenc encoder.

voaacenc is not installed by default in gst-plugins-bad for mac. I so I had to use

`brew reinstall gst-plugins-bad --with-libvo-aacenc`

The following pipeline worked well with my application.

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=3 mp4mux name=mux ! \
 filesink location=xxxx.mp4 souphttpsrc location=<hls url> ! decodebin name=decode  ! \
 videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw, framerate=50/1 ! queue ! x264enc ! mux. decode. ! \
 audioconvert ! voaacenc ! mux.
```

Also in my HLS stream video segments some had 50FPS and some had 59.97FPS. So I used a videorate to default to 50. This might need to change depending on your segments

For those folks who want a C++ code of the same, please checkout my [github](https://github.com/ggovindan/gstreamer_examples) page